# MySQL Query - Grouping Values and Aggregrating

Tags: mysql, sql

I fire the following query to my table :

```
SELECT code_ver, 
       platform_type, 
       category_name 
FROM   builds 
WHERE  runtype LIKE 'test' 
       AND platform_type NOT LIKE 'total'; 

+-----------+---------------+---------------+
| code_ver  | platform_type | category_name |
+-----------+---------------+---------------+
| 10.0.1.50 | 8k            | UMTS          | 
| 10.0.1.50 | 8k            | UMTS          | 
| 10.0.1.50 | 8k            | IP            | 
| 10.0.1.50 | 8k            | IP            | 
| 10.0.1.50 | 9k            | IP            | 
| 10.0.1.50 | 9k            | IP            | 
| 10.0.1.50 | 9k            | UMTS          | 
| 10.0.1.50 | 9k            | UMTS          | 
| 10.0.1.50 | 9k            | UMTS          | 
| 10.0.1.50 | 9k            | Stability     | 
| 10.0.1.50 | 9k            | Stability     | 
| 10.0.1.51 | 8k            | UMTS          | 
| 10.0.1.51 | 8k            | UMTS          | 
| 10.0.1.51 | 8k            | IP            | 
| 10.0.1.51 | 8k            | IP            | 
| 11.0.1.50 | 9k            | UMTS          | 
| 11.0.1.50 | 9k            | IP            | 
+-----------+---------------+---------------+
```

I fire the following query

```
SELECT code_ver, 
       platform_type, 
       Count(*) 
FROM   builds 
WHERE  runtype LIKE 'test' 
       AND platform_type NOT LIKE 'total' 
GROUP  BY code_ver, 
          platform_type; 

+-----------+---------------+----------+
| code_ver  | platform_type | count(*) |
+-----------+---------------+----------+
| 10.0.1.50 | 8k            |        4 | 
| 10.0.1.50 | 9k            |        7 | 
| 10.0.1.51 | 8k            |        4 | 
| 11.0.1.50 | 9k            |        2 | 
+-----------+---------------+----------+
```

And when I fire the following query

```
SELECT code_ver, 
       platform_type, 
       Count(*) 
FROM   builds 
WHERE  runtype LIKE 'test' 
       AND platform_type NOT LIKE 'total' 
GROUP  BY code_ver, 
          platform_type,
          category_name; 

+-----------+---------------+----------+
| code_ver  | platform_type | count(*) |
+-----------+---------------+----------+
| 10.0.1.50 | 8k            |        2 | 
| 10.0.1.50 | 8k            |        2 | 
| 10.0.1.50 | 9k            |        2 | 
| 10.0.1.50 | 9k            |        2 | 
| 10.0.1.50 | 9k            |        3 | 
| 10.0.1.51 | 8k            |        2 | 
| 10.0.1.51 | 8k            |        2 | 
| 11.0.1.50 | 9k            |        1 | 
| 11.0.1.50 | 9k            |        1 | 
+-----------+---------------+----------+
```

But I want the count of unique combinations of (code_ver + platform_type + category_name) such that the output should look like this :

```
+-----------+---------------+----------+
| code_ver  | platform_type | count(*) |
+-----------+---------------+----------+
| 10.0.1.50 | 8k            |        2 | 
| 10.0.1.50 | 9k            |        3 | 
| 10.0.1.51 | 8k            |        2 | 
| 11.0.1.50 | 9k            |        2 | 
+-----------+---------------+----------+
```

Can anybody give me some suggestion here.

Comment: Is this the valid check as per the values of platform_type column `AND platform_type NOT LIKE 'total'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a SQL inner query.

```
SELECT ta.code_ver, 
   ta.platform_type, 
   Count(*) 
FROM (SELECT code_ver, platform_type
      FROM   builds 
      WHERE  runtype LIKE 'test' 
          AND platform_type NOT LIKE 'total'
      GROUP  BY code_ver, platform_type, category_name) AS ta -- table alias
GROUP BY ta.code_ver, ta.platform_type;
```

Comment: I already tried this one, it does not give me the aggregated results for each platform type...it does do the counting....but does not give the desired output

Comment: That is exactly what I said ... should have stuck to my guns.

Comment: @PiHorse I think I've understood your question better now. Please test this new query.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO That's incorrect! SQL allows you to even drop every column you're doing a `GROUP BY` on and just keep `Count(*)` in the resultset.

Comment: @Ravi: I tried exactly the same query, but it says 'Every derived table must have its own alias'. I tried creating an alias for the inner query, but I guess I might be wrong with the syntax

Comment: @PiHorse Use the AS clause after the subquery. Answer updated.

Comment: @PiHorse On some databases you may have to qualify field names with the table alias. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the result set you provided, it looks like you want to also group by `category_name`

```
    SELECT code_ver, 
           platform_type,
           Count(*) ,
           category_name
    FROM   builds 
    WHERE  runtype LIKE 'test' 
           AND platform_type NOT LIKE 'total' 
    GROUP  BY code_ver, 
              platform_type,
              category_name;
```

Comment: I already tried this one, it does not give me the aggregated results for each platform type...it does do the counting....but does not give the desired output

Comment: @PiHorse What exactly is the issue? Could you please clarify

Comment: I added the result of your suggested query in the edit...can you please have a look at that.

Comment: @PiHorse Could you explain (just in plain english) how you're getting just `2` for `10.0.1.50 | 8k   ` ?